# parseInt blank field

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm writing an age verification actionscript for a flash project.  Right now I have it where if the user is born before a certain year it will allow them to access the swf if not it will deny them.  the problem is if they leave the field blank it will allow them access (i'm assuming because a blank field qualifies it as acceptable to the parseInt) so i'm curious as to how to block it so if someone doesn't enter a year it will disallow them from access the swf.  here's my code for it

agetext._visible = false;
verify_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
  if (parseInt(year.text)<=1992){
  _root.age._visible = false;
     }

else {
     agetext._visible = true;
      };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `parseInt` can't parse a valid Number, it will return `NaN` (Not a Number). You can check for this by using `isNaN`:

```
// check that year is not NaN and is <= 1992
var birthyear = parseInt(year.text);
if (!isNaN(birthyear) && parseInt(birthyear)<=1992) {
```

Alternatively, you can check to be sure that the TextField isn't blank:

```
if(year.text != null && year.text != "" && parseInt(year.text) <= 1992) {
```